# How to skip a forum's confirmation page?

Tags: javascript, redirect, greasemonkey

I'm writing a Greasemonkey script for a forum where, if you hit "Submit" on a post you've written, you will be taken to a notification page saying 'Your post has been posted".

I'm trying to get around this by skipping this page entirely.

So far the only solution I've come up with is:

```
// @include        *posting.php?mode=reply*
// ==/UserScript==
// @run-at document-start

{
location.href = document.referrer
}
```

It's probably a complete roundabout way, but it's not quite what I was looking for. I'm hoping to skip the confirmation page entirely and just reload back to the page you were just at immediately. I've tried `history.go(-1)` as well, but no dice.

Any ideas how to achieve something along those lines?

Comment: Does this code not load the correct page?  It should on many forums.  If so, what is the problem?  Not scrolled to the last post?  We need exact details of the forum too. Exact URL is preferable; forum type (EG "phpBB") at a minimum.

Comment: The problem is that it still loads the next page, rather than skipping it entirely. You post - confirmation page - and then it returns. My script still loads the conf page, and then goes back to the thread again. I wish to skip the conf page entirely. It's a phpBB 3 forum and the urls in questions would be.. .com/viewtopic.php?(viewing/replying using quick reply) -> goes to .com/posting.php?mode=reply(This is the page I wish to skip). If possible, only when the 'Submit' button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your script did not work well, is there are errors in the code you posted.  The [metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) is corrupt and the `@run-at` directive is outside of the block.

Additional issues:

1. You probably should use `location.replace()` to keep the confirmation page from cluttering up the history and the back button.
2. `@include *posting.php?mode=reply*` will slow all of Firefox down unnecessarily.  This is because Greasemonkey will have to do a *deep*, character-by character comparison of every URL.

   Don't start `@includes` (or just about any comparison in any programming language) with a multi-char wildcard if you can help it.  Better to have multiple includes like so:

   ```
   // @include     http://SITE_1/posting.php?mode=reply*
   // @include     http://SITE_2/posting.php?mode=reply*
   //etc.
   ```

So, this script should work well enough for you:  In practice, you'll never see the confirmation page (I use this technique myself) :

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Whatever
// @include     http://SITE_1/posting.php?mode=reply*
// @include     http://SITE_2/posting.php?mode=reply*
// @include     http://SITE_3/posting.php?mode=reply*
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

location.replace (document.referrer);
```

Note that approaches like [Rab Nawaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595513/331508) can give a better UI experience, but it is not as simple as his answer shows.  You need to capture many forms, buttons, and links -- on a typical forum page.  Everything does not post to the same destination, and how you would handle the results varies wildly depending on the action.

The `location.replace()` is a good tradeoff of UI smoothness against potentially large code complexity.

Comment: That's -exactly- what I was looking for Brock, thank you. Is there a way I could make it trigger only when a specific button is pressed? (i.e the Submit button, since there's another page with the same url that doesn't work anymore thanks to this script)

Comment: Yes, you can narrow down when it fires, maybe by comparing URL parameters, or the referrer.  Worst case, could get complicated.  I can't get more specific without **precise details** of when you want to skip the redirect and when you don't.  Exact URLs are the best bet. Screenshots might help. ... It looks like this question, as stated, was answered.  Might be best to open a new question with the additional changes needed and the details required for us to help you.

Comment: I wouldn't hesitate to throw up another question had I not thought this case in of its own was so ridiculous and petty haha. There's just this one small step, and unless it's beyond complicated, I'd absolutely love to be able to close this case and finish this up once and for all. I threw together this picture real quick to further explain my slight problem, hopefully it clarifies what I'm trying to do: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v418/Dumle/temp/b3ac07db.png I realize I'm pushing my luck here, but I'm beyond thankful for all the help received thus far from everyone here.

Comment: Since the response-page URL is the same, and the referring-page URL will be the same, then the only recourse is for Greasemonkey to act on both page types -- which is not hard but is a little more involved.  I don't have access to a phpBB3 forum that has "Quick reply" enabled, so please open a new question.  Include the HTML code for both types of buttons and the form code that surrounds each.  What I have in mind will require altering the form post URL(s) slightly.

Answer (score 0):

do your posting with AJAX. then you can avoid going the message page. just get the response and do whatever you wanna do with it.

jquery based ajax

```
   $("#submitButtonId").click(function() {

    var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: That's the thing though, I have no idea how to get the 'response' in question.

Comment: First off I'd like to thank both of you for replying, and especially Rab for updating his answer and following up with actual code. I am, however, still at a loss I'm afraid and I feel just awful asking for even more assistance. Is it possible I could be so crude to have it explained to me in an even more simplified way? Is there any information I could give you that would make this easier to explain? Once again, I'm terribly sorry.

Comment: which part your having problem understanding

Comment: Honestly, I start questioning myself at the first line. The #submitButtonId will have to be either 'button1 roadblock' or 'submit'. As for the third line, I'm unsure of which script is being referred to there. Would that be the page at hand i.e */*/viewtopic.php, the page where the submit button is, or *posting.php?mode=reply*, which is the page I'm trying to skip? (also I'm guessing the code wont support asterisks so if either of the two are the case, how would I go about making those lines wildcards, so to say? As for the rest - I'm lost. Not sure what #idForm is referring to.

Comment: This is not a jQuery question.  Nor is this answer well-applicable to a Greasemonkey scenario.